# highlighting an active tab with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-manipulation

I am creating a tabbed navigation bar wherein when the tab is active it should change its color the color that i set it to change with. Navigating thru the pages with the tabs works fine however the color highlight on the active tab just don't seem to work.

here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<section class="tab" id="active_Current_Tabs">
      <header>Active/Current Tabs</header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="btn currentTab" onclick="activeTab(event, 'lorem7')">TAB1</li>
          <li class="btn currentTab" onclick="activeTab(event, 'lorem8')">TAB2</li>
          <li class="btn currentTab" onclick="activeTab(event, 'lorem9')">TAB3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main class="main-doc">
        <article class="selectedPage" id='lorem7'>
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, est?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="selectedPage" id="lorem8">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, est?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="selectedPage" id="lorem9">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, est?</p>
        </article>
      </main>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
article {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

/*navbar css*/

nav {
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #8b9d98;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #d7e0e0;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: .5s;
}

/*main css*/
main {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*Active/Current Tab */

#lorem7 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #49c2a4;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#lorem8 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color:#35386f;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#lorem9 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color:#e28968;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// active/current tab function

function activeTab(evnt, currPage) {
  var currenttab;
  var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedPage');
  for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  //for dehighlighting inactive tabs
  currenttab = document.getElementsByClassName('currentTab');
  for(j = 0; j < currenttab.length; j++) {
    currenttab[j].className = currenttab[j].className.replace("green", " ");
  }
  document.getElementById(currPage).style.display = "flex";
  evnt.currentTarget.className += "green"; //this appends the color to active tab
}
```

help please! T_T

Comment: it seems that you set a "className" to "green" here `evnt.currentTarget.className += "green";` but there is no ".green" in your CSS .. AND to add a class it should be `element.classList.add("yourclass");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the "green" class because there were no rules for it in your CSS.  I answered the question assuming you wanted the active tab to be the same color as the active page.  Sorry if that's not what you intended, but I think it makes sense.

To avoid problems with specific class names, you can use .classList methods like "add" and "remove".  This way you don't have to worry about the order of class names in the markup. Examples:

```
tabs[i].classList.remove('active')
e.currentTarget.classList.add('active')
```

You can also attach your event listener (click handler) dynamically to keep your HTML uncluttered. Example:

```
for(j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
    // attach event listener to all tabs
    tabs[j].addEventListener('click', clickTab)
}
```

You can also make your CSS less repetitive by assigning similar styles to a common class:

```
.page {display:none;}
.page.active {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I modified your IDs in order to be able to reference tabs and pages independently without explicitly passing parameters to the click handler functions. Example:

```
<li id="t2" class="tab">TAB2</li>
...
<article class="page" id="p2">...</article>
```

Here is my JS Bin:

http://jsbin.com/defidih/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: I actually just want to highlight the active tab. green was the color i can think of but this is pretty neat! I am new to front end development by the way. so you may think this is a simple task but this is pretty impressive for me to manipulate a dom like that. is there a like button here somewhere to like this answer?

Comment: Oh! so that's what the up button is for! Thanks @jstein

Comment: there's a new developer born every minute! ;-) thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`evnt.currentTarget.className += "green";`

This line will add to the already existing className.

So your class `class="btn currentTab"`
becomes `class="btn currentTabgreen"`
instead of `class="btn currentTab green"` if you didn't add green to it before.
So it would better to use `currenttab[j].className.replace("green", "");` to reset the previous green classes and `evnt.currentTarget.className += " green";` to set the new green class.

Edit: this does imply that the classname will keep growing with one space every time. SO the optimal would be to use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` instead of manually editting the class string.

```js
function activeTab(evnt, currPage) {
  var currenttab;
  var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('selectedPage');
  for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    pages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  //for dehighlighting inactive tabs
  currenttab = document.getElementsByClassName('currentTab');
  for(j = 0; j < currenttab.length; j++) {
    currenttab[j].className = currenttab[j].className.replace("green", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(currPage).style.display = "flex";
  evnt.currentTarget.className += " green"; //this appends the color to active tab
}
```

```css
article {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}

/*navbar css*/

nav {
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #8b9d98;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #d7e0e0;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: .5s;
}

/*main css*/
main {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*Active/Current Tab */

#lorem7 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #49c2a4;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#lorem8 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color:#35386f;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#lorem9 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color:#e28968;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="tab" id="active_Current_Tabs">
      <header>Active/Current Tabs</header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="btn currentTab" onclick="activeTab(event, 'lorem7')">TAB1</li>
          <li class="btn currentTab" onclick="activeTab(event, 'lorem8')">TAB2</li>
          <li class="btn currentTab" onclick="activeTab(event, 'lorem9')">TAB3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main class="main-doc">
        <article class="selectedPage" id='lorem7'>
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, est?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="selectedPage" id="lorem8">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, est?</p>
        </article>
        <article class="selectedPage" id="lorem9">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, est?</p>
        </article>
      </main>
    </section>
```

Comment: lol! I am laughing at myself for missing that. didn't realize i didn't have a default color! Thanks @Shilly

Answer (score 0):

To create a tabbed navigation bar wherein when the tab is active it should change its color to a custom color that you have set. You could use this few lines of vanilla JavaScript.

JS:

```
var activeTab;
var acctOptions = document
  .querySelector(".account-options")
  .querySelectorAll("li");
acctOptions.forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (activeTab) activeTab.classList.remove("active");
    activeTab = option;
    activeTab.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  background: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="account-options">
   <li class='login'><a>Login</a></li>
   <li class='register'><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
   <li class='account' ><a>My Account</a></li>
   <li class='reward-points'><a>Reward Points</a></li>
   <li class='password-reset'><a>Reset Password</a></li>
   <li class='logout'><a>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```