# How can I toggle the active class for tabs created in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I know how to make a CSS tab component for regular HTML and CSS, but do not know how to do it when in for loop. I know this is Shopify, but problem is really how to make a tab component with for loops. I want the first index in loop to have the active class first (first tab is selected by default) but when I use the `forloop.first`, its somewhat hardcoded.

I do not know how to use JavaScript to add/remove a class (to show content based on tab clicked) when in a for loop for tabs component

HTML (Shopify Liquid)

```
<div class="tab-wrapper">
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    <div id="tab-{{ forloop.index }}" class="{% if forloop.first %}tab-active{% endif %}">
  {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    <div id="content-{{ forloop.index }}" class="content content-active">
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tab-active {
  color: red;
}
.content{
  display: none;
}
.content-active {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript: ?

Comment: Doesn't Shopify have that functionality baked in (or available via plugin)? Seems odd that you'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: you need to write js to handle such things. liquid will render the page once, after that js takes over

Comment: Otherwise you'd just use a click handler, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388416/highlighting-an-active-tab-with-vanilla-js.

Comment: @isherwood Going with custom solution and look so gotta build myself. Plus not going to pay a subscription for basic tabs.

All set, yeah just had to play around a bit