# how can i make navbar items bigger on current page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i want my navbar items to get bigger when im on the page that theyre linked to, for example if im on the home section i want the home button to be bigger and if im on about section i want the about button to get bigger. i tried the js script but idk why its not working
here's the code

```css
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    left: calc(50vw - 25vw);

}
#navbarlist{
    top: 50px;
    left: 25vw;
    width: 50vw;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbaritem{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.navbaritem:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.current{
    transform: scale(1.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: aqua;
}
.home{
    background-color: rgba(216,157,255,1);
}
.about{
    background-color: rgb(236,136,183);
}
.products{
    background-color:rgba(255,115,115,1);
}
.services{
    background-color:rgba(255,179,111,1);
}
.contactus{
    background-color: rgba(255,253,106,1);
}
#home{
    width: 100vw;
}
#homeheader{
    font-size: 140px;
    position: relative;
    top:75px;
    transform: rotate(-3.4deg);
}
.sections{
    width: 100vw;
}
#aboutheader{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 70px;
    top: 500px;
}
#aboutuspart{
    font-size: 140px;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <nav id="navbar">
                <ul id="navbarlist">
                    <li class="navbaritem home"><a class="" href="#home">home</a></li>
                    <li class="navbaritem about"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li class="navbaritem products"><a href="#products">products</a></li>
                    <li class="navbaritem services"><a href="#services">services</a></li>
                    <li class="navbaritem contactus"><a href="#contactus">contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

i have tried to make that happen with js but its not working and i cant figure out why

Comment: Does this answer your question? [highlighting an active tab with vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388416/highlighting-an-active-tab-with-vanilla-js)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you're iterating over `document.links` before the content of the page is ever loaded. You need to wait for the DOM to be ready!

Eg.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   /* Iterate the links here! */
});
```

The second problem is that you're using anchor tags for your links currently, so you never actually go to a new page, where your class adding logic would run again.

There are a ton of solutions to making the links reactive to the anchor tag eg `#about`, look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68371679/490790).

Here's a simple one (if you stick with anchor urls):

```js
function addCurrentToUrl() {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    if (document.links[i].href === location.href) {
      document.links[i].classList.add("current");
    } else {
      document.links[i].classList.remove("current");
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  addCurrentToUrl();
});

window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  addCurrentToUrl();
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but the issue with this solution is that it makes the link itself bigger and not its container i want the container to get enlarged

Comment: Simply add/remove the class to the parent element then, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

Answer (score 0):

To activate the current link on click, you can add an event listener to each link that sets the `current` class to the clicked link and removes it from any other links.

here is the updated code example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-item-bigger-xrgnhm

Comment: gotta add that code here on stackoverflow